# Cookies setting automatically in swift

Tags: swift, cookies

I am working on storing the cookies of my app. 
I am calling the  setcookie() method of `HTTPCookieStorage` class.

**to set cookie :**

```
let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: responseheader, for: response.url!)
    for cookie in cookies {
      var cookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]()
      cookieProperties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name]    = cookie.name
      cookieProperties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value]   = cookie.value
      cookieProperties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain]  = cookie.domain
      cookieProperties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path]    = cookie.path
      cookieProperties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version] = NSNumber(value: cookie.version)
      cookieProperties[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires] = cookie.expiresDate

      let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)
      HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(newCookie!)
    }
```

**To Get cookies from cookie store:**

```
for cookie in HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies! {
  print(cookie)
}
```

**To delete cookie**

```
for cookie in HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies! {
  HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)  
}
```

But, even if I comment the setcookie method , cookie is automatically setting. How is it possible ? 
cookie in the header and cookie in cookie-store are same even though I am not calling the set cookie method

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the [default](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage/1410415-cookieacceptpolicy?language=objc) `cookieAcceptPolicy` of the `HTTPCookieStorage`. That is `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways`